# bash not finding function when new bash shell open

Tags: bash

I am on MacOS. I recently upgraded to Mojave. I'm running the Homebrew version of GNU bash, version 4.4.23(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin17.5.0).

When I open a new bash shell by issuing the `bash` command, I get the following error every time I issue a new command:

**`bash: parse_git_branch: command not found`**

The error is getting generated from the following line in my `.bashrc` file that customizes my command line with the git :

`export PS1="\[\033[32m\]iMac5K@ \[\033[33;1m\]\w:\[\033[m\]\[\033[33m\]\$(parse_git_branch)\[\033[00m\] "`

(Note: my `.bashrc` file is sourced by my `.bash_profile` file.)

The `parse_git_brach` is in my `.bashrc` file so I'm not sure why I am getting this error. Even after I manually source `.bashrc`, I still get the error.

Issuing `which bash` yields:

`/usr/local/bin/bash`

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you just run `bash` without `-l` or `-i`, it doesn't execute `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc` itself, but only honors variables it received through the environment.

When you `export` a variable, you're exposing it to child processes... *through the environment*.

So, your child shell receives the PS1 definition, but it *doesn't* receive the function that `PS1` requires!

You have some options here:

- Export the function alongside the `PS1` definition that uses it. That is, `export -f parse_git_branch`. This has an important caveat in that only shells which read exported functions (which is to say, in practice, bash) will get any benefit from this fix.
- Stop exporting the PS1. That is, just take the `export` off the line `PS1='...'`.
- Set `BASH_ENV=$HOME/.bashrc` and `ENV=$HOME/.bashrc`, which will instruct even noninteractive shells to run `.bashrc` (of course, this can change the way scripts execute, and is thus at a risk for causing bugs in other software; moreover, the latter means your `.bashrc` needs to be written to be safe for non-bash shells).

Comment: OK, everything working now per your suggestion above to not export `PS1.` Thanks.

Comment: If the OP is running `bash` (rather than `bash someScript`), then the shell should be interactive by default, and `.bashrc` *should* be sourced. Exporting the function shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: Hmm. Unless stdout or stderr has been redirected, you're right -- which implies that one of them *has* been (perhaps through `tee` or such for logging?)